# Just as in Segmentation, can different addresses in Paging also point to the same physical memory location?

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, memory-address, microprocessors

Eg. for segmentation, 0000:FFFF is equivalent to 0001:FFEF (Just a hypothetical case, don't know if we really use these in programming or if these are reserved spaces)

(I am new to assembly programming. Specifically x86.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0000:FFFF` is equivalent to `0001:FFEF` only in real mode, VM86 mode, or SMM mode. In these modes, by definition, paging is not enabled. In protected mode<sup>1</sup> without paging, they are necessarily translated to different physical addresses because the segment offsets are different (`FFFF` vs. `FFEF`) but the segment base address is the same<sup>2</sup>. With paging, when the segment offsets get added to the segment base address (which could be zero), they may either point to the same virtual page or different virtual pages, but either way, the the least 12 significant bits of the page offsets would be different (because the least 12 significant bits of the segment offsets are different) and so they cannot be equivalent irrespective of how the page tables are set up.

In general, different addresses may translate to the same physical address. When the page offsets are different but the least significant 12 bits are same nonetheless, it is possible for the logical addresses to get translated to the same physical addresses when they point to pages of different sizes. Otherwise, if at least one of the least significant 12 bits is different in the virtual addresses, they cannot be equal in the physical address space.

---

1. In protected mode, the segment selector 0000'0000'0000'00XX<sub>b</sub> is used as null segment selector and cannot be accessed. But Let's assume for the sake of argument that it is accessible (or consider 0000'0000'0000'0100<sub>b</sub> vs. 0000'0000'0000'0101<sub>b</sub> instead).
2. They refer to the same segment because the segment selector indices (the most significant 13 bits of each selector) and table indicators (the third least signficant bit) are equal

Comment: Note that in protected mode, even without paging, segments don't work the same way as in real mode.  In protected mode, segments are looked up in the local and global descriptor tables (ldt and gdt) which contain base addresses lengths and some other data for each segment selector. These can be configured as desired and segments can overlap arbitrarily.

Comment: Address translation on x86 works by first computing a *linear address* from the segment and offset and then looking up this linear address in the page table (or using it directly if paging is disabled). This first step is completely independent of paging.  It absolutely doesn't matter if paging is enabled or not for how segmentation works.

Comment: @fuz Yes, I already know that. Which part of my answer indicates otherwise? Are you the one who downvoted my answer? Because I don't understand why.

Comment: You say “In protected mode without paging, they are necessarily translated to different physical addresses because the segment offsets are different.” That's not generally correct because multiple segments can overlap and the segment base can be arbitrary (with a granularity of 1 or 4096 iirc).  Note further that neither 0000 nor 0001 are valid segment selectors as they are reserved as null pointers.

Comment: @fuz The first paragraph discusses two specific far pointers, not a general discussion. But in general, you're right. The second paragraph is about paging, and pages cannot arbitrarily overlap like segments. Good point regarding the null segment selector. I've fixed that. You could have just told me what's wrong with my answer rather than just downvoting!

Comment: I have not downvoted you (in fact, you got an upvote from me).  I think the text is still misleading because you don't explain why the segment base addresses are the same (because 0000 and 0001 refer to the same segment with different RPLs), making your answer sound like all segments have the same base address or something equally nonsensical.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is allowed.  In fact, not only is this legal, it's also frequently used for a feature known as *shared memory.*